# OGR to read from Oracle, and then write a CSV

Tags: csv, ogr2ogr, oracle-dbms

I need to read an Oracle (not Spatial) table with OGR.

I have no problem with ogrinfo. I use this command:

> ogrinfo -ro OCI:user/password -sql "select * from HR.EMPLOYEES"

I have this kind of output:

```
OGRFeature(select * from HR.EMPLOYEES):106
  EMPLOYEE_ID (Integer) = 206
  FIRST_NAME (String) = William
  LAST_NAME (String) = Gietz
  EMAIL (String) = WGIETZ
  PHONE_NUMBER (String) = 515.123.8181
  JOB_ID (String) = AC_ACCOUNT
  SALARY (Real) =  8300.00
  COMMISSION_PCT (Real) = (null)
  MANAGER_ID (Integer) = 205
  DEPARTMENT_ID (Integer) = 110
```

Now I would like to export (in example) in CSV format, using OGR. This is the command:

> ogr2ogr -f "CSV" test.csv OCI:"user/password" -sql "select * from HR.EMPLOYEES"

I have this errors:

```
ERROR 4: Failed to create test.csv\select * from HR.EMPLOYEES.csv:
Invalid argument
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation from sql statement.
```

I'm not able to find the syntax error.

What's wrong?

I'm using GDAL/OGR 1.9 and Oracle 11g for windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try adding -nlt NONE, in case it's a table without geometries

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the -sql parameter should be positioned before the destination file:

```
ogr2ogr -f "CSV" -sql "select * from HR.EMPLOYEES" test.csv OCI:"user/password"
```